# LPC1769 how does FIOPIN work?

Tags: c, gpio

I'm currently working on GPIO on the LPC1769 and I have a question that I do not quite understand. Supposing I have the following code lines:

```
LPC_GPIO2 -> FIODIR = 0xFFFFFFFF;
FIO_SetMask(2, 0xFFFF0000, 1); 
LPC_GPIO2-> FIOPIN = 0xAAAAAAAA;
a = GPIO_ReadValue(2);
```

Now in this case, the 1st 4 are masked FFFF but why does a give me 0x00002AAA? How did the FIOPIN affected the bits?

Comment: @unwind right, but isn't the case here is `0xFFFF0000`? 4 words, I would say.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I meant the FFFF in this case. Yes 4 words

Comment: Not familar with this cpu but when you write to a GPIO port and read back, you might not read what you wrote. External circuitry might drive some pins and the read is actually on the pins, not on the state of the flip flops driving the output. For FIODIR I assume you configured them as outputs, with 0xFFFFFFFF, right?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I was not trying to correct you, I was trying to back you up but got a bit (heh) too terse. My point is that `0xffff0000` is not masking 4 bits, it's masking 4 * 4 = 16 bits. I have no idea what you or @Bolo mean by "words" in this context.

Comment: @unwind right. I meant _nibble_.

Comment: You should really download *LPC17xx User manual* (UM10360). It has almost all information you will ever need.

Answer (score 4):

As  written in the datasheet of LPC1769, page 16:

> Port 2: Port 2 is a 32-bit I/O port with individual direction controls for
>   each bit. The operation of port 2 pins depends upon the pin function
>   selected via the pin connect block. **Pins 14 through 31 of this port
>   are not available.**

Then all bits from 31 to 14 are always 0.

You set the port to 0xAAAAAAAA but the last set bit is bit 13, then 0x00002AAA

Answer (score 0):

That's because your device only have GPIO on port 2 from P2[0] to P2[13], so obviously P2[14] to P2[31] will always be 0.